# SQLException Prepared Statement: Input parameter not set, index: 1

Tags: java, jdbc

Hi I am trying to do batch upload to sybase iq using JDBC prepared statements. I am getting the following sql exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: JZ0SA: Prepared Statement: Input parameter not set, index: 1.
```

EDIT:

```
INSERT INTO School2(schoolid,schoolname,schooltype) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

I am using the following code

I am new to JDBC please guide what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us your query string !

Comment: And the content of `newArray`

Comment: Hi @TheNewIdiot Thanks for the reply. I have added the query in edit section.

Comment: Hi @MarkRotteveel contents of array is {1,ABCSChool,HighSchool} like for each line the same kind of contents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not see your query string but it seems that all the parameters are not set when you execute the statement.

Specifically, I don't think `pstmt.executeBatch();` should be found in your for-loop setting the parameters: you execute the batch before setting all the parameters!

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for the reply. I have added the insert query in question. Please tell me how do I set parameters before calling execute batch.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is caused by the fact that you call `pstmt.addBatch()` and `pstmt.executeBatch()` for every iteration over `colArray`. You should only call `pstmt.addBatch()` after you have set **all** query parameters, and only call `pstmt.executeBatch()` once all objects have been processed (or you've reached your batch size).